# One or four tables? (db structure)

Tags: database, data-structures, language-agnostic

Items are connected to:
one or more "region" and/or
one or more "county" and/or
one or more "city" and/or 
one or more "place".

My question is how I should set up the relations:

```
id | thingID | regionId | countyId | cityId | placeId
```

or

4 `tables`?

```
id | thingId | regionId

id | thingId | countyId

id | thingId | cityId

id | thingId | placeId
```

or is there perhaps another better solution?

Comment: Do things have multiple locations, where each location is region, county, city, place? Or is each "link" between the item and the things it is connected to logically different?

Comment: i would choose the 2nd solution because you can add/remove extra columns in the table, for example at city table \you can add a post code/ a telephone prefix at country table etc..

Comment: @willem Things can have multiple locations. And I may choose "city" without activating that region. So if I search for a region, that thing will come up (based on the fact that the city is connected to that region), but it's clear that the thing only belongs to a city which happens to be inside that county.

(Not sure if that helps?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be overthinking this, but I think there's probably a relationship between "region", "county", "city" and "place" - an item that belongs to a "place" should also belong to the city, county and region.

You can solve this in both the designs you provide - but you need a fair amount of additional logic. In the first solution, you need to make sure that every time you insert a record, you populate the location from "left to right" - a record with only "place" is not valid.

In the second solution, you need to populate all relevant rows - an item in Chelsea must also have records for London, Middlesex and South East England.

There's another way...

```
Table: location
ID     Name                 Parent
------------------------
1     South East England    null
2     Middlesex             1
3     London                2
4     Chelsea               3
5     Kent                  1
6     Canterbury            5


Table: item
Id     name
-----------------
1      Posh Boy
2      Cricket ground
3      Rain

Table: item_location
ItemID    LocationID
--------------------
1        4    //Posh boy in Chelsea
2        2    // Cricket ground in Middlesex
3        1    // Rain in the South East of England.
```

Comment: I don't disagree that there might be a structure that includes some sort of hierarchy between types of locations, but even then I don't think it can be a direct one-to-many between them.  For example, cities can cross multiple counties.

Answer (score 1):

The second option is clearly better.  It's a many-to-many relationship for each of these categories, and that's what the second option describes.

The first option would result in some very odd data.  If you had a ThingId that was associated to all of the different types once, you would have one row that had all the columns filled in.  Then if your ThingId needed to be tied to an additional city, you would have another row that had only the cityId filled in, with the other columns remaining null.

A table design that results in a lot of null values is usually (not always) a sign that your model is flawed.